Can you save presets for the Viewer Node in Geometry Nodes?
Recently I am working with the Viewer Node in Geonodes A LOT, the only thing that annoys me is that I have to go to the N Panel to change the Type of Data I want to inspect, i.e. getting confused forever why everything is white till I see it is set to Boolean instead of Float. Best thing would be to move this from the N Panel to the Viewer but I know this here isn't Right Click Select, so I wanted to know if there is a way to preset the Viewer to Vector so it shows potentially every type of Data correctly?
Also is it true that Blender computes the Nodes connected to the Output even if I use the Viewer Nodes on something different? I wondered because sometimes it is very slow but the Geometry in the Viewer Node is super simple.
Do you have any other useful tips to smoothly work with Viewer Nodes?
Best,
Todesdigga
